# Should I create Swing components within Actions?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am creating Actions for my Swing components, however, they often need to generate a confirmation JDialog. Should I be creating this JDialog within the Action itself, should I pass it in to the Action, or is there an alternative method?

Example

```
public static class Create extends AbstractAction {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...);
        // ... processing
    }        
}
```

This example is quite hard to unit test since it involves automating the selection of the JDialog (which feels like a code smell).

**Solution?**

```
public static class Create extends AbstractAction {

    private JDialog dialog = null;

    public Create(JDialog dialog) {
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        dialog.display();
        // ... processing
    }        
}
```

Comment: Personally, so long as the requirement is the always the same, I would create the dialog in the action.  This makes the action self contained.  This then raises the question of should you pass a reference to the parent component.  The answer to the is, it depends...

Comment: But that  kills me when testing my controllers...

Comment: How so?  The intention of an Action is to isolate resuable code into a single package

Comment: But unit testing Swing GUIs are hard - and if a GUI bakes its way into my controllers (Actions), then I run into a problem testing all my controllers.

Comment: That's not a problem with the action, that's a limitation of the unit test.  Yes unit testing UIs is difficult, but there are projects available, based on JUnit to test Swing applications, have a Google.  Your unit test shouldn't be determining your application design

Comment: It's not a problem with the unit test, though, since the unit test is assuming the controller is isolated from the UI - which, in this case, it's not. I suppose my question, rephrased, is, "How do I isolate my JDialogs from my controller logic?"

Comment: @sdasdadas One solution that I find quite "pretty" is to isolate your GUI-calls into interfaces and use dependency injection to resolve the implementations. In a unit test, you can then use a different implementation that does not involve real graphic components. Combined with Mock objects (such as the one provided by EasyMock or Mockito), you can even verify that your graphical components will properly be called. Of course, this implies a lot of design upwards. This could also virtually mean that you could switch to a different technology than Swing and not have to re-implement everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep the dialog creation in actionPerformed, and move the following processing logic into a separate method, and then unit-test *only* that method. Dialog creation just works, there is no need to unit-test it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something roughly like this:

```
class Dialogs {
    public static Dialogs INSTANCE = new Dialogs();

    public int confirm(String message) {
        return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message);
    }
}
```

Then call `Dialogs.INSTANCE.confirm()` everywhere you would call `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()`. For testing, set `Dialogs.INSTANCE` to a mocked value.

Comment: That seems like it provides less benefits (and more global access problems) than simply passing in a JDialog object.

Comment: In the real world I would make INSTANCE accessible only through a getter, and use reflection or a testing-only API to set it. I was just trying to give the outline of a solution. Passing in a `Dialog` loses you the simplicity of the `JOptionPane` methods.